# how can I convert a twilio return into json and print on html page?

Tags: ruby, json, twilio

I am using sinatra and ruby with [twilio-ruby gem](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby). I get a list of numbers with the following code:

```
@numbers = @subaccount.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local.list({:area_code => '858'})
puts "Available numbers:"
num = @numbers.each {|num| puts num.phone_number} 
{number:num}.to_json
```

In the terminal window it appears a list, like so:

```
Available numbers:
+18589240128
+18588779651
+18582231372
+18589141380
+18588779811
+18589141390
+18582231256
```

etc. cut for brevity.

But on the website page it appears as:

```
{"number["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]}
```

So my question is: how can I convert the return, from Twilio, into usable json so that I can access it through jquery getJSON and then print it on my HTML page?

Many thanks as always ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, as I can't get the same result in testing. However, I think it has something to do with the way you are using `puts` and `each`.

You appear to be trying to get the `num` array to be an array of phone numbers, however `each` just returns the original array, so you remain with an array of objects.

Try the following:

```
@numbers = @subaccount.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local.list({:area_code => '858'})
puts "Available numbers:"
num = @numbers.map {|num| puts num.phone_number; num.phone_number } 
{number:num}.to_json
```

Map will return an array with the result of the block in place of the original array, so this will print out the phone number with `puts` and then return the phone number itself. Then your `num` array is just an array of those phone numbers and should read out correctly in the json.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

change these two lines and try once:

```
num = Array.new
@numbers.each {|n| num << n.phone_number }
{number:num}.to_json
```

Comment: this works too and is beautifully simple. The Twilio evangelist was, I believe, the first to respond. Thank you I will use this method with other similar coding situations, I am grateful for your help.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, if I can make one comment on this one though, `map` does what the first two lines in this example does. My answer probably looks more complicated as I kept the `puts` in. It could be written more simply as `num = @numbers.map { |n| n.phone_number }`.